# VSTS/Azure Devops Dashboard Widget into image

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have been looking for a way to capture the data or display of a VSTS/Azure DevOps Dashboard widget (e.g. the CFD widget) into an image file.
I have looked at methods to call the widget via the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/dashboard/widgets/get%20widget?view=vsts-rest-4.1) v4.1.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}/widgets/{widgetId}?api-version=4.1-preview.2
```

But it only returns JSON data about the widget, what I am looking for is a way to capture the widget data into an image file (png, jpg), instead of going to the widget in a web browser and saving the image to file.

It would be great to be able to achieve this using `invoke-RestMethod` in PowerShell to be able to call the widget via the API and export/save/download the widget data as an image file as it is displayed in the web client UI.